# Помогите составить SQL запрос

Tags: phpmyadmin, база-данных, php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(c.id), 0) AS count, s.id, s.name
 FROM section_catalog s
 JOIN
 catalog c
 ON (s.id = c.id_cat)
 GROUP BY c.id_cat
 ORDER BY s.name ASC";
```

В результате должен выводить следующее:

```
name 1 (0 шт)
name 2 (0 шт)
name 3 (4 шт)
name 4 (5 шт)
name 5 (0 шт)
```

Но выводит только

```
name 1 (0 шт)
name 3 (4 шт)
name 4 (5 шт)
```

те все записи, в которых `count>0`, и первую запись с `count 0`
Сломал всю голову, **как исправить данный запрос?**

Comment: Как минимум ER-диаграмму добавьте к вопросу

Comment: Всё проще), есть таблица с ID и названием раздела и есть таблица с товарами нужно вывести все разделы и количество товаров. Проблема в том что если товаров нет количество не выводится

Comment: попробуйте **left** join

Comment: чем запрос

`SELECT COUN(*) cnt, s.id, s.name FROM section_catalog s JOIN catalog c ON (s.id = c.id_cat) GROUP BY c.id_cat ORDER BY s.name ASC`

вам не понравился?

Answer (score 1):

Как написал Yura Ivanov в своем комментарии, Вам нужен `left join` (или `left outer join` - как Вам больше нравится):

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(COUNT(c.id), 0) AS count,
    s.id,
    s.name
FROM
    section_catalog s
    LEFT JOIN catalog c ON (s.id = c.id_cat)
GROUP BY c.id_cat
ORDER BY s.name ASC
```